# Codeblocks c++ multithreading huge error list

Tags: multithreading, c++11, codeblocks

I was playing around with some multithreading example code shown below (taken from from http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/multithreading_win32A.php) using codeblocks (build option was set to c++11).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD WINAPI myThread(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    unsigned int& myCounter = *((unsigned int*)lpParameter);
    while(myCounter < 0xFFFFFFFF) ++myCounter;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    unsigned int myCounter = 0;
    DWORD myThreadID;
    HANDLE myHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, myThread, &myCounter, 0, &myThreadID);
    char myChar = ' ';
    while(myChar != 'q') {
        cout << myCounter << endl;
        myChar = getchar();
    }

    CloseHandle(myHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

When I built the project the "cwchar" file was opened and I got the huge list of "has not declared" errors shown below. I'm not sure what's wrong here, any ideas?

```
||=== Build: Debug in TEST2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|177|error: '::wcscat' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|178|error: '::wcscmp' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|179|error: '::wcscoll' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|180|error: '::wcscpy' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|181|error: '::wcscspn' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|183|error: '::wcslen' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|184|error: '::wcsncat' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|185|error: '::wcsncmp' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|186|error: '::wcsncpy' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|188|error: '::wcsspn' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|193|error: '::wcstok' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|196|error: '::wcsxfrm' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|204|error: '::wcschr' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|205|error: '::wcspbrk' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|206|error: '::wcsrchr' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|207|error: '::wcsstr' has not been declared|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar||In function 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|213|error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|212|note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcschr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar||In function 'wchar_t* std::wcspbrk(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)':|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|217|error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|216|note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcspbrk(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar||In function 'wchar_t* std::wcsrchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)':|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|221|error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|220|note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcsrchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t)'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar||In function 'wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)':|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|225|error: invalid conversion from 'const wchar_t*' to 'wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|224|note:   initializing argument 1 of 'wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h|358|error: 'wcslen' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 21 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: It's not clear how you're building things - I wonder if the use of the windows.h header and mingw is causing trouble

Comment: Yes it is the windows.h that is causing the problem, I commented out everything except an empty main function and built and I got the same errors. I don't know how to fix it though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by moving the `#include <windows.h>` line from it's original position to below the `#include <stdio.h>` line. Includes now look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

Don't ask my why it worked lol.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the error message, you have a typo in your code:

```
    HANDLE myHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, myThread, &myCounter;, 0, &myThreadID;);
```

Remove the extra ';' from this line and you should be fine!

Comment: I removed the extra semicolons but this doesn't fix the problems with the cwchar file, I've updated the question code and error dump.