# How can I fix c++ cwchar error in code blocks?

Tags: c++

Hi I have an error with c++ in code::blocks. every time I try to compile my code I get these errors in the cwchar file (Which is a program file or something so I don't want to edit it and mess it up)

> ::wcscat has not been declared 
>   ::wcscmp has not been declared

And other "::" lines have the same error. I can't find where the error occurred in my code and I have a lot of code so I can't copy&paste it.

Comment: Might also be a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303445/codeblocks-c-multithreading-huge-error-list).

Answer (score 0):

Any `::` refers to a global function. Those declarations are typically coming from includes.

If you Google the name of your function it will tell you which include you need to use.